# How to focus edit text again after assigning it focusable = false

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an edit text. I have set focusable = false in the xml layout. But when I am tapping a button I want that it gain the focus again and I could now edit the text. But I can not do this even after setting focusable = true.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_display_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_shape"
        android:text="Display Name"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_profilePic" />
```

Even after doing this I could not edit the text as the cursor is not visible and the keyboard is not popping up.

```
etDisplayName.focusable = View.FOCUSABLE
        etDisplayName.requestFocus()
        etDisplayName.isCursorVisible = true
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the EditText editable again, you need to set the focusable property to true and also set the cursorVisible property to true. You can do this programmatically in your activity or fragment.

Here's an example code snippet:

```
// Get reference to the EditText
EditText etDisplayName = findViewById(R.id.et_display_name);

// Set focusable and cursorVisible properties to true
etDisplayName.setFocusable(true);
etDisplayName.setCursorVisible(true);

// Request focus on the EditText
etDisplayName.requestFocus();
```

With this code, you should be able to tap the button and the EditText will become editable again, with the cursor visible and the keyboard popping up.